# Getting around container covariance in C++/STL

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, containers, covariance

First lets start with the problem. I have a tree, and I want to do the following:

```
class Base {
    std::vector<Base*> children_;
};

class DerivedA : public Base {
    //adds some members
};

class DerivedB : public Base {
    void AddChildren(std::vector<DerivedA*> children, int position) {
        //Do stuff based on the fact that it's a DerivedA
        //Add to the list of children_ 
    }
    void AddChildren(std::vector<DerivedB*> children, int position) {
        //Do stuff based on the fact that it's a DerivedB
        //Add to the list of children_ 
    }
};
```

I'm running into the container co-variance issue - a `std::vector<DerivedA*>` (or `DerivedB*`) is not the same as a `std::vector<Base*>`. But at the same time I don't want to create a whole new vector in `AddChildren` just to add them to the `std::vector<Base*>`.

So is there a way I can add the vector directly to the list of `children_` without too much performance overhead?

The things I've considered and don't particularly like:

- Going through and adding each element individually
- Creating a new `std::vector<Base*>` to add to `children_` (unless a compiler can optimise this away?)
- Passing in a `std::vector<Base*>`, and dynamic_cast'ing each element.
- Passing in a `std::vector<Base*>`, inspecting the first element via a `dynamic_cast` and then using `static_cast` for the rest.
- Making `AddChildren` a templated function (I couldn't think of how to make it work since the `std::vector` is stored away and then AddChildren is called sometime later).

I could reinterpret_cast but it's dangerous, what about a Union? Is this dangerous?

```
union DerivedBUnion {
    std::vector<Base*>     base_;
    std::vector<DerivedB*> derivedB_;
}
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What’s wrong with `children_.insert(children_.end(), children.begin(), children.end())`? Before you think about all sorts of casts, wouldn’t it make sense to establish that the straightforward solution would pose a performance problem at all?

Comment: Thank you for the reality check. For some reason I thought that wouldn't work (without actually going to the effort of checking) because the underlying vectors were of different types. I did not fully understand iterators.